# finding angle and scalar c

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

matrix $$A = \pmatrix{ 4&-5\\5&4}$$

is standard matrix of a linear transformation from $R^2 \to R^2$ that consists
of a rotation through an angle composed with multiplication by a scalar $c.$ Find angle (to the
nearest thousandth of a radian) and $c.$

I found that the eigenvalues are: $4+5i$ and 
$4-5i$ along with the corresponding eigenvectors  $(i,1)$ and $(-i,1).$

how would I go about in finding the angle and scalar $c?$

Comment: What's the determinant of $A$? What does the determinant tell you?

Comment: the determinant is 41, which tells me that the matrix is invertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we will divide all the entries of the matrix by $\sqrt{4^2 + 5^2} = \sqrt{41}.$ we can now write the matrix $$A = \pmatrix{ 4&-5\\5&4} = \sqrt{41}\pmatrix{ 4/\sqrt{41}&-5/\sqrt{41}\\5/\sqrt{41}&4/\sqrt{41}} = \sqrt{41}\pmatrix{\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t &\cos t}  $$ in a much simpler form.

the matrix $A$ represents a linear transformation that is composed of two simpler ones:(a) a transformation that magnifies by a factor of $c = \sqrt 41$, (b) then another that rotates counter clockwise by an angle $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac4{\sqrt{41}} = \right) = 0.8960$

so the angle of rotation is $0.8960 $ and the magnifying factor is $\sqrt{41}.$

Comment: why to you sqrt the 41? If possible may you place a link to this theorem ? But thank you.

Comment: @Learn, see my edit. i divided  by $\sqrt{41}$ so that matrix columns and rows have unit length and the matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: so is the scalar in this case sqrt(41) or 1/sqrt(41) since you mentioned you divided?

Comment: @Learn,   scalar $c$ is $\sqrt{41}$ you can think of multiplying and dividing  by $\sqrt{41}$ we kept one outside and moved the other inside the matrix.

Comment: okay thank you, still a little confused, I'll do some online reading.

Comment: if possible may you cite a source, im having trouble finding something

Comment: i really don't know a source but you can try the kit linear algebra mat18.06 videos by prof. strange. he is very good at explaining things.